# Change default Word font without using normal.dotm

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, windows-registry, microsoft-office

I am looking for a way to set default font across our domain without touching normal.dotm.

Some of our users actually have set different settings for their work that are stored within normal.dotm.

The easy (and usual) way would be replacing every normal.dotm with our pre-configured one. 
In our case we would have to replace it again as soon as somebody changed anything within the normal.dotm to make sure the default font wasn't changed therefore all user defined settings get deleted.

Is there any different way to approach and solve this? GPO, Registry?

Comment: You could probably script changing this one style in normal.dotm only.

Comment: @eckes the normal.dotm is impossible for me to decypher. do you have a suggestion as how to do this?